# Select and link in one line

Tags: html, layout

I want to set select and link in one line, but select is upper.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <a id="back" href='#' data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn-left" data-theme="b" data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
    <select name="menu" id="menu" data-inline="true" data-theme="b"  data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="menu" selected="true">Menu</option>
        <option value="index.html">Home</option>
        <option value="services.html">Services</option>
        <option value="technology.html">Technologies</option>
        <option value="how_we_work.html">How we work</option>
        <option value="about.html">About Us</option>
        <option value="careers.html">Careers</option>
        <option value="contacts.html">Contacts</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "select is upper"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/b8TNd/) for me in FF8. What browser are you using?

Try setting your `<select>` to `display: inline` in your CSS. The `<a>` is inline by default, so doesn't need setting.

```
select#menu {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine in Chrome, but still doesn'twork in FF 8.0.1

Comment: I'm only up to FF 8.0, so I can't test it. In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: As I say select is upper that link

Comment: @Wolandello, do you mean its above the link?  "upper" is a drug, or part of a shoe.

Comment: @Inuyasha TIL "upper" is a drug and also part of a shoe. It also appears I'm not alone in my confusion.